# How can I work with multiple Go projects locally?

Tags: go

I'm working on multiple projects in go using modules.

Project 1: github.com/company/project1

```
/
  - /auth
      - service.go
  - main.go
  - go.mod
```

Project 2: github.com/company/project2

```
/
  - /cart
      - service.go
  - main.go
  - go.mod
```

If I have in my project2/go.mod next import: `github.com/company/project1` and I already created both projects on Github.

How can I test both projects locally? I mean, without pushing test code (on project1) and using `go get github.com/company/project1` previously because I just want to push my last commits when I finish both codes (project1 and project2).

Comment: [Can I work entirely outside of VCS on my local filesystem?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem)

Comment: `replace` statement is indeed a key in such situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@CeriseLimón](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5728991/cerise-lim%C3%B3n) and [@oakad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2702398/oakad) pointed out in their comments, using `replace` in your `go.mod` files allow to use local copies of a repo instead of requiring to commit the project that is a dependency.

Project 2's `go.mod`:

```
module github.com/company/project2

require (
  ...
  github.com/company/project1 v0.0.0
)

replace github.com/company/project1 => LOCAL_PATH
```

Replace `LOCAL_PATH` for your relative path from project2 to project1, for example, if both are find under `$GOPATH/src`, `LOCAL_PATH` would have to be replaced by `../project1` (considering that the project1 directory is named project1). You should also replace v0.0.0 to another version if it applies (this is, if project1 has different versions, the line inside the requirte block should point to the right version. The ellipsis (`...`) represents any other dependency of your project2.

**NOTE:** you should not push the `replace github.com/company/project1 => LOCAL_PATH` line to your VCS unless every developer uses the same relative path **and** you have some sort of automated or manual way of removing that line before releases, as you do not want that line to be present in releases.

Comment: I wish not to have to comment on those lines when I push my code, but I understand that this is the better way to work with projects locally. Thanks.

Comment: You usually have the `module` and the `require` block pushed, and the `replace` line never gets commited. There was a suggestion to allow to place this line in a different file (something like `go.local.mod`) which you could just add to `.gitignore` and forget about it, but I don't think it managed to get implemented.